# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Reader_Exception' with message 'Could not open for reading! File does not exist

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, file-upload, phpexcel

In my script i´d like to read a .xls file with "browse & input file", then i wan´t PHPExcel to read/load the .xls and insert the cell values into mysql.

I had this script working with static file: $path = 'file.xls';
But i can´t get the upload script to work with my code.

ERROR:
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Reader_Exception' with message 'Could not open for reading! File does not exist

Can someone please tell me what´s wrong?
Or is there some code i'm missing?

HTML Select file:

```
<form class="form-horizontal well" action="php/import_excel.php" method="post"  name="import_excel" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <h4>Ladda upp tabell</h4>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
                                Bläddra&hellip; <input type="file" multiple>
                            </span>
                        </span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
                    </div>
                    <span class="help-block">
                        Välj en excel fil
                    </span>
                    <div class="pull-right">
                        <button type="submit" id="submit" name="Import" class="btn btn-primary  button-loading" data-loading-text="Loading...">Ladda upp</button>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                </form>
```

PHP Read and insert to mysql:

```
//Load phpexcel includes    
require '../Classes/PHPExcel.php';
require_once '../Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

//Establish connection to mysql
$conn=mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die("Could not connect");
mysql_select_db($dbname,$conn) or die("could not connect database");

//Load file
if(isset($_POST["Import"])){
echo $path=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

//$path = "atbl.xls";
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($path);

//Loop threw file to get data
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
    $worksheetTitle     = $worksheet->getTitle();
    $highestRow         = 20; //$worksheet->getHighestRow(); // e.g. 10
    $highestColumn      = 'G'; //$worksheet->getHighestColumn(''); // e.g 'F'
    $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
    $nrColumns = ord($highestColumn) - 64;

//Echo file info
echo "<br>The worksheet ".$worksheetTitle." has ";
echo $nrColumns . ' columns (A-' . $highestColumn . ') ';
echo ' and ' . $highestRow . ' row.';
echo '<br>Data: <table border="1"><tr>';

//Loop threw colum, rows and cells
for ($row = 11; $row <= $highestRow; ++ $row) {
    echo '<tr>';
    for ($col = 0; $col < $highestColumnIndex; ++ $col) {
        $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
        $val = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
        //$dataType = PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::dataTypeForValue($val);
        echo '<td>' . $val . '<br></td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
}

for ($row = 11; $row <= $highestRow; ++ $row) {
$val=array();
for ($col = 0; $col < $highestColumnIndex; ++ $col) {
$cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
$val[] = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
}
//Insert data from file to mysql 
$sql="INSERT INTO phpexcel(objekt_nr, objekt_rev, element_nr, element_langd, element_bredd,  element_hojd)
VALUES ('".$val[0] . "','" . $val[1] . "','" . $val[2]. "','" . $val[4]. "','" . $val[5]. "','" .   $val[6]. "')";
//echo $sql."\n";
mysql_query($sql) or die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
}
?>
```

Comment: It helps if you actually describe the problem you're having. An error messages (either on screen or in logs)? What debugging you've tried, etc

Comment: can you add something from your PHP error log?

Comment: If you're getting a 500 error, then that's a server-side issue, and you need to check the server logs.... a common cause might be a parse error in your script: `php -l` from the command line can help identify that

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Reader_Exception' with message 'Could not open for reading! File does not exist.'

Comment: I'm not using any target folder because i actually don't wana save the file on my server. Is this correct?

Comment: @MarkBaker So, what you think?

Comment: Permissions in your temp folder? File hasn't uploaded successfully?

Comment: Thank you Mark Baker very much for being so kind to a gut who are trying to learn. The script PHPexcel is by the way awesome! And it´s guys like you who makes the world keep on spinning!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML code was missing name & id:

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" multiple>
```